# Import Error at /admin/

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I seem to have a problem  for awhile now i just cant understand.

While trying to go into my Django admin site, i keep getting import error at /admin/ no module named tools. The thing is, i had an app named tools, but removed it from the project. But am still getting the import error at admin, no module named tools. After a bit of googling on stackoverflow, i found a article that suggested deleting all pyc files as they contain old data still being referenced, which makes sense. But after removing every pyc file i could see in my current project directory i still get the error.

Heres where it gets weird.

I am using django_tables2. I also have a books app which tracks books information. I created a table class for the books app and specified a table column to be a link column. When viewing the index page of the books app i get the import error at /books/ no module named tools, yet there is no reference to tools at all in the books app?? I get the same error import error at /admin/ no module named tools. But if i change the LinkColumn in the books app table class back to a normal column, just changing the verbose name, the error goes away with the books app index page but still persists with admin?? I honestly have no clue whats going on here.

Edit: Even after starting a new tools app and registering it in admin.py its the same error. The only thing i can think of its a path error but how and why, if it can find the other apps in the same directory?

I am more than willing to post any code i have if required but i have no idea where to even start looking.

```
Traceback:
File "django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  215. return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198. return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
  358. model_dict['admin_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % info, current_app=self.name)
File "django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  480. app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  310. self._populate()
File "django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  285. lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  229. self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32. result = func(*args)
File "django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  100. not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40. __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/
Exception Value: No module named tools
```

Comment: Do you have any leftover .pyc files in any of your directories?

Comment: Yes. It took a while but i went through each folder and checked for any pyc at all. Deleted them all, then restarted the server to try again but with the same error.

Comment: Could you post the traceback of your error?

Comment: Added the traceback. Im just not sure if i pasted it correctly. After re-adding the tools app to the project, if i try go to the tools index. I get import error at /tools/ no module named tools. Now im really confused. So it is finding the tools app?

Comment: I've experienced an error like this before, got it working by commenting out url patterns in urls.py. There may be a rouge import in one of your views and since your admin panel imports all views found in your url patters, try commenting them out 1 by 1 and you might spot the culprit.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you :) That would have been the last thing i thought of, so i'm sure i would have been stuck for ages on this. Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles upon this question:

I've experienced an error like this before, got it working by commenting out url patterns in `urls.py`. There may be a rouge import in one of your views and since your admin panel imports all views found in your url patters, try commenting them out 1 by 1 and you might spot the culprit.